# Testing if two algebras are isomorphic

Tags: sagemath

Wish to establish if two finite-dimensional finitely-presented algebras (over rationals) are isomorphic, either through some built-in functionality or a brute force computation. Anybody know how/if sage can do this?

Comment: Yes, it can do it. I use GAP for it, which is integrated into SAGE. What dimension are your algebras?

Comment: @DietrichBurde They're both 64-dimensional, what functionality do you use to do this?

Comment: For Lie algebras I use "LieAlgebraIdentification" from the LieAlgDB package. If your algebras $A$ and $B$ are Lie-admissible, i.e., if $[a,b]=ab-ba$ satisfies the Jacobi identity, then $A\cong B$ also implies $L(A)\cong L(B)$ for their Lie algebras. For other algebras see [here](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap62.html).